# How to fix 'no prototype' when using php & behat

Tags: php, bdd, behat

Good day. I'm learning some PHP BDD testing with Behat. I've been following closely this `Behat 3` tutorial: http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/quick_start.html

I'm on Windows 10, using php 5.6.33. I've added `composer.phar` and `composer.json` to my project folder and the latter file looks like this:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "~3.0.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.1.0"
    }
}
```

Then, as tutorial suggests, I run commands in the following order:

1. `php composer.phar install`.
2. `vendor/bin/behat --init`.
3. I've placed `sample.feature` file into `features` folder.

Feature file looks like this:

```
Feature: Product basket
  In order to buy products
  As a customer
  I need to be able to put interesting products into a basket

  Rules:
  - VAT is 20%
  - Delivery for basket under £10 is £3
  - Delivery for basket over £10 is £2

  Scenario: Buying a single product under £10
    Given there is a "Sith Lord Lightsaber", which costs £5
    When I add the "Sith Lord Lightsaber" to the basket
    Then I should have 1 product in the basket
    And the overall basket price should be £9

  Scenario: Buying a single product over £10
    Given there is a "Sith Lord Lightsaber", which costs £15
    When I add the "Sith Lord Lightsaber" to the basket
    Then I should have 1 product in the basket
    And the overall basket price should be £20

  Scenario: Buying two products over £10
    Given there is a "Sith Lord Lightsaber", which costs £10
    And there is a "Jedi Lightsaber", which costs £5
    When I add the "Sith Lord Lightsaber" to the basket
    And I add the "Jedi Lightsaber" to the basket
    Then I should have 2 products in the basket
    And the overall basket price should be £20
```

But when I run `vendor/bin/behat --init` I get this exception which actually do not prevent code snippets from being generated:

```
    ReflectionException: Method FeatureContext::__construct does not have a prototype in D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Behat\Context\Reader\AnnotatedContextReader.php on line 86

    Call Stack:
        0.0054     237328   1. {main}() D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\bin\behat:0
        0.5684    2249712   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(???, ???) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\bin\behat:31
        0.7328    2785200   3. Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun(class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:117
        5.8172   12067888   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application.php:102
        5.8180   12068848   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(class Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command, class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:193
        5.8181   12069424   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:843
        5.8252   12079976   7. Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command->execute(class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:241
        5.8558   12157688   8. Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->execute(class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command.php:63
        5.9129   12222752   9. Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->testSpecifications(class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, array(2)) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController.php:108
        5.9802   12264200  10. Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingExercise->test(array(2), bool) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController.php:146
        5.9802   12264432  11. Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeExercise->test(array(2), bool) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingExercise.php:70
        6.0493   12324584  12. Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingSuiteTester->setUp(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment, class Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator, bool) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeExercise.php:69
        6.0691   12342664  13. Behat\Testwork\Hook\Tester\HookableSuiteTester->setUp(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment, class Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator, bool) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingSuiteTester.php:59
        6.0976   12359008  14. Behat\Testwork\Hook\HookDispatcher->dispatchScopeHooks(class Behat\Testwork\Hook\Scope\BeforeSuiteScope) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Hook\Tester\HookableSuiteTester.php:63
        6.0976   12359192  15. Behat\Testwork\Hook\HookRepository->getScopeHooks(class Behat\Testwork\Hook\Scope\BeforeSuiteScope) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Hook\HookDispatcher.php:57
        6.0976   12359280  16. Behat\Testwork\Hook\HookRepository->getEnvironmentHooks(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Hook\HookRepository.php:67
        6.0977   12359352  17. Behat\Testwork\Environment\EnvironmentManager->readEnvironmentCallees(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Hook\HookRepository.php:50
        6.0977   12359600  18. Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\Reader\ContextEnvironmentReader->readEnvironmentCallees(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Testwork\Environment\EnvironmentManager.php:115
        6.0978   12360208  19. Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\Reader\ContextEnvironmentReader->readContextCallees(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment, string(14)) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\Reader\ContextEnvironmentReader.php:66
        6.1051   12363528  20. Behat\Behat\Context\Reader\ContextReaderCachedPerContext->readContextCallees(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment, string(14)) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\Reader\ContextEnvironmentReader.php:87
        6.1052   12363616  21. Behat\Behat\Context\Reader\AnnotatedContextReader->readContextCallees(class Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment, string(14)) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Behat\Context\Reader\ContextReaderCachedPerContext.php:52
        6.1052   12365152  22. Behat\Behat\Context\Reader\AnnotatedContextReader->readMethodCallees(string(14), class ReflectionMethod) D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Behat\Context\Reader\AnnotatedContextReader.php:64
        6.1053   12365328  23. ReflectionMethod->getPrototype() D:\Projects\php-projects\local-behat-phpunit-2\vendor\behat\behat\src\Behat\Behat\Context\Reader\AnnotatedContextReader.php:86
```

I've just started to learn PHP, but as far as I understand it interface `AnnotatedContextReader` indeed does not have a prototype for `__construct` method, but mentioned interface extends `Context` interface and this one has such method prototype. So, I decided to skip that exception for the time being and completed provided tutorial. I can run my behat tests, but console is full of `ReflectionExceptions` complaining about absence of prototypes for my test steps. This drastically increases execution time and definitely should not be happening. Any ideas of what am I doing wrong? For code snippets please refer to tutorial link I've provided.

Comment: Can you paste your _behat.yml_ config file?

Comment: Use latest php and set `FeatureContext implements Context`

Comment: @gvf I've followed tutorial mentioned in the post and they don't suggest creating one. As far as I understand behat uses some default values if no _behat.yml_ file provided?
Also, I'm trying this out with php7 on Ubuntu right now. Upgrading is not an option for me, but maybe I'll catch the source of this exception.

Comment: Can you post your feature context file and location?

Comment: @lauda, I already do `FeatureContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext` in my `bootstrap.php` file. Unless I can have multiple php versions at the same time upgrading to php7 is not an option for me.

Comment: @gvf, can you please refer to http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/quick_start.html#automating-steps ? I've got exactly this layout.

Comment: @gvf weird, no reflection exceptions on Ubuntu with php7.. I shall check if it's a module issue and get back to you, probably tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is a bit embarrasing. After some digging around I've discovered that this behaviour has nothing to do with version of `php` I'm using. Exception trace was shown because I had `xdebug` extension enabled and configured to show all possible output. So I believe this is why my console was full of `ReflectionException`s and test execution was extremely slow. setting this line resolved my issue:

```
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
```

On the other hand it doesn't explain to me why `ReflectionException` happens in the first place, it just masks exception trace. I understand that this is because missing method prototypes in base interfaces, but is this done intentionally?